# Why does the compiler find my function if is not yet declared?

Tags: c++, overload-resolution

Contrary to my expectations, this program works:

```
#include <iostream>


namespace a { struct item{}; }
namespace b { struct item{}; }


template<typename T>
void func(T t) { do_func(t); }


int main()
{    
    func(a::item{});
    func(b::item{});
}


namespace a { void do_func(item) { std::cout << "a::func\n"; } }
namespace b { void do_func(item) { std::cout << "b::func\n"; } }
```

Output:

```
a::func
b::func
```

Verifications with online compilers:

- [gcc 4.8](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=50ae4963600287160615db268097e40e-ad3febf7a884bab73e56b6ba60c751d7)
- [clang 3.4](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=50ae4963600287160615db268097e40e-e223fd4a885a77b520bbfe69dda8fb91)

If the instantation of `func<T>` occurs in the body of `main` then I would expect that `a::do_func` and `b::do_func` are not yet declared.

How can this work?

#### Update

According to @Marc Claesen the reason that above works is:

> template instantiation is performed after reading all of the source

However, then why does this code does *not* work:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
void func(T t) { do_func(t); }

int main()
{
    func(1);
}

void do_func(int) { std::cout << "do_func(int)\n"; }
```

See [gcc-4.8](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=246a098bf4e0df9e832ef295ed4755a4-52831655b029a2d6a3c79838b51b0d2d):

```
error: 'do_func' was not declared in this scope,
and no declarations were found by argument-dependent
lookup at the point of instantiation [-fpermissive]
```

[clang++ 3.4](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=246a098bf4e0df9e832ef295ed4755a4-e223fd4a885a77b520bbfe69dda8fb91):

```
error: call to function 'do_func' that is neither
visible in the template definition nor found by
argument-dependent lookup
```

So it seems that the combination of function template and ADL are required to make it work.

However, I don't understand why this is so..

Comment: Because the compiler is smart!

Comment: But it seems to be very selective about what it is smart and about what it is stupid. (E.g. the program fails if `func` is a normal (non-template) function.)

Comment: Magic Templates are filled with Magic.

Comment: Removed my answer because I was clearly missing part of the story. Excellent question, though!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It works because of two interesting things:

- **two-phase name lookup** which is performed to lookup *dependent* names.
- and Argument Dependent Lookup (ADL).

Have a look at this:

- [The Dreaded Two-Phase Name Lookup](http://blog.llvm.org/2009/12/dreaded-two-phase-name-lookup.html)

In short, `do_func` is a dependent name, so in the first phase (when the file is *only* parsed but the function template is *not* instantiated) the compiler does **not** resolve the name `do_func`, it *only* checks the syntax and it sees it is a valid function call. That is all. In the second phase when the function template is instantiated (and thus `T` is known), the name `do_func` is resolved and at this time it also uses ADL to lookup the name.

Note that ADL works only for user-defined types. It doesn't work for built-in types, which is why your second code (i.e `func(1)`) doesn't work!

Comment: Right, one should test it on VC++2010 to prove.

Comment: Can you justify that the selected specialization is well-formed at each point of instantiation?

Comment: @LucDanton: I didn't understand your question. Could you rephrase it?

Comment: This [slightly modified program](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=da858a1d050013e0dc62ee3ffb62c698-7063104e283ed82d51a6fde7370c6e59) is rejected by Clang, although not GCC: when the (this time) explicit instantiation takes place, there is no overload of `do_func` yet declared to be found by ADL. What is the difference when the instantiation is implicit?

Comment: LucDanton: Hmm. I've to dig the spec more to find an answer to that. Lets see if I find one. Maybe, [@Johannes](http://stackoverflow.com/users/34509/johannes-schaub-litb) can help us.